# SAP crystal report not displaying in server 2003 after hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Developed a SAP Crystal Report in ASP.Net 4.0. Works Perfectly in local machine and when hosted in Windows 7 and XP environment. But when deployed the same in client machine the report is not displaying. No error message! it does not show when a click event occurs.
Client machine: Server 2003
Installed: CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_5 from SAP. on Server

Am I missing something.?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You say there is no error message. Well, if the client machine you are trying to install to has Windows Server 2003, it probably will not have .NET Framework 4 (and above installed). CR 13 requires > .NET 4 to render reports.

I believe that Server 2003 may be too old to run what you want. Take a look at the articles [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1936665.aspx?Crystal%20reports%20are%20nor%20displaying%20on%20the%20server%202003%20) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/287543/Crystal-Reports-not-rendering-when-webpage-is-serv) to see how to proceed.